# IBM Bluemix and websocket 400 error

Tags: node.js, websocket, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use the websocket module for node.js to interface with the IBM Watson Speech to text api.  When I try to connect I get a 400 error and I'm not really sure why... I've never used websockets before. Here is my code creating the socket and trying to connect

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client,
    client = new WebSocketClient(),
    token = 'myToken==',
    wsri = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=' + token;

//some event handlers for on connect and on connectFailed

client.connect(wsri, null, null, null, null);
```

Here is the response I get

```
Connect Error: Error: Server responded with a non-101 status: 400
Response Headers Follow:
content-type: text/html
x-dp-watson-tran-id: csf_platform_prod_dp01-735083801
set-cookie: Watson-DPAT=this_is_a_cookie; path=/speech-to-text/api; secure; HttpOnly
www-authenticate: Basic realm="IBM Watson Gateway Log-in"
x-backside-transport: FAIL FAIL
connection: close
```

any ideas how to fix this??

EDIT-UPDATE:  Germans answer below is correct.  I wasn't calling the  authorization endpoint to get a token and was trying to use my bluemix credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use WebSockets you first need to get a `token` calling the `authorization` api. Then you will add that `token` into the `url`.

The Websocket url is:

```
wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=TOKEN
```

Where `TOKEN` can be created by doing (example in curl):

```
 curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD  "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are your service credentials.

That's basically a `GET` request to

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token
```

with a `url` query parameter that is the service you want to get the token for. In this case:

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api
```

---

If you are using nodejs, I would suggest you to use the `watson-developer-cloud` npm module. Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/germanattanasio/359580d99ea22f47c6ba) snippet which shows you how to do real time transcription using the Speech to Text service.

Answer (score 0):

Watson's Speech-to-Text Service does not support Web Sockets. [A detailed explanation can be found here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/174846/using-websockets-in-speech-to-text.html).

You are going to need to use a different protocol. A guide to connecting to Watson's API via Node.js can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-quick-nodejs.shtml#quickStart).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Ben, we now support web sockets. In fact, the demo uses WebSockets and the authorization api.